# How would i change the colour dynamically depending on the width

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

OK so I have a bar that depending on the percentage set will fill to that set percentage.

However how could i change this the have a transition of the colour depending on the percentage.

For example 
0% to 25% red the slowly turn green as approaches 100%

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
.progress:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:0; 
    width:90%;
    -webkit-animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
    animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes filler {
    0% {
        width:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes filler {
    0% {
        width:0;
    }
}
@keyframes filler {
    0% {
        width:0;
    }
}
```

any help on this will be fantastic, thanks you.

Comment: Javascript....CSS can't do that. You'll need JS anyway to change the percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `linear-gradient` here and animate `:after` pseudo-element to translate on **X axis** and gradually reveal parent element beneath with gradient.

Also `animation-fill-mode: forwards` is to keep `:after` to the right side once animation has finished.

```css
.progress {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 25%, green 100%);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress:after {
  content: '\A';
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
  animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes filler {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes filler {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
@keyframes filler {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HTML5 progress element:

```
<progress></progress>
```

And you can give style like this:

```
progress[value] {
  //your style
}
```

You can find an example usage in [this](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) link.

Comment: Please clarify how this would change color **dynamically**. The link you provided does not seem to cover that....and **that** seems to be the requirement here.

Comment: I wanted to explain; if you firstly set colors by percentage of progress bar -which i gave a basic example above-, when you trigger its percentage (by changing progress width) with JS, you don't have to set color with JS anymore. You have to only control percentage by JS and then it automatically set the color (or another style variables).